# Can a macOS package installation failure message be customized?

Tags: macos, pkgbuild, productbuild

I have a customized macOS package installer that only executes scripts created by something like the following:

```
pkgbuild --identifier com.example.hello --scripts scripts --nopayload intermediate.pkg
productbuild --distribution distribution.dist --resources resources final.pkg
```

If the `preinstall` or `postinstall` script were to fail, the installer GUI displays a default message ***The installation failed.** The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.*

Is there anyway to customize this error message similar to what `productbuild` provides for customizing welcome and conclusion content?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?